# How to generate SQL Script for database changes in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Professionally I work with SQL Server. So I am used to using the Visual Studio tools that is capable to generating a script for the database changes that I made, so that I can use that script on the server. ( I know there are other more automated ways to do it)

For my freelance projects I use Laravel. I was wondering how I can generated a script for the database changes after a certain point or migration in Laravel without having to point my development environment to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. after writing your migration you can run

```
php artisan migrate --pretend
```

this will show the sql query that would be run.

Comment: Okay. So I think I would restore my local database to the schema of the database on the server. Then run this command ( php artisan migrate --pretend ) to see the scripts to run on the server. How does that sound?